# Javascript Array - i tried a lot but have not got the answers correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am New with array. can someone please help me.

```
const array =["ron","rexona","danzial","alexander"];
```

Q1 - Write a function that will return an `array` whose 
contents are all items in `array` that has greater than 4 characters

```
['alaska','orlando','phoenix','orlando','alaska'];
```

Q2 write a function that takes an `array` of state and outputs an
object like the following representing the number of occurrence of each country.

```
{
   alaskaa: 2,
   phoenix: 1,
   orlando: 2,

}
```

Here is what i tried

```
enter code here
<script>
var i, len,pc;
var name=["ron","rexona","danzial","alexander"];
len=name.length;
function test(){

for(i=0;i<len;i++){
pc += name[i];
}
}
console.log(pc);
</script>
```

Comment: You have to do a research and add what have you tried because there is a lot of content in StackOverflow to solve your questions.. Regards

Answer (score 1):

First question:

```
array.filter(string => string.length > 4);
```

Second:

```
array.reduce((obj, state) => {obj[state] = (obj[state] || 0) + 1; return obj}, {});
```

**And For reference you can go through**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

**and**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Yes , You can implement this method . For reference you can go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter    and  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce